# retrieve remote machine details using c# , wmi

Tags: c#, asp.net, wmi, wmic

I'm retrieving machine details using c# and wmi. I'm using the following code to retrieve information:

```
        ManagementScope scope =new ManagementScope(@"\\"+strIPAddress+@"\root\cimv2");
        SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery();
        query.QueryString = "select  * from Win32_OperatingSystem";           
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
        ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
        {
         //////////////////////////////////
        }
```

It's working fine for windows operating system, but it doesn't work for linux or Citrix server.

I've also tried this code below :

```
         string strURL="http://www.google.com"; 

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURL);
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response =(HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
            string strServer= response.Server;           
        }
        catch (WebException wex)
        {
          // Safe cast to HttpWebResponse using 'as', will return null if unsuccessful
            var httpWebResponse = wex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
            if (httpWebResponse != null)
            {
                var httpStatusCode = httpWebResponse.StatusCode;

                // HttpStatusCode is an enum, cast it to int for its actual value
                var httpStatusCodeInt = (int)httpWebResponse.StatusCode;
            }
        }
```

It doesn't  give me the remote server os name, rather it gives me IIS name.

When I searched over internet, I found the following site:

http://uptime.netcraft.com/

Where anyone can retrieve information. Can anyone tell me how  it works or how we can fetch these details using c#.

Comment: WMI is Windows Management Instrumentation.  As the name implies, WMI does not work on non-Windows OSes.  Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @ Nilpo , is there any script to get details of non-Windows machine like netcraft does.